# PHP's DatePeriod class giving inaccurate results

Tags: php, datetime, period

I have the following simple PHP code:

```
$timeRange = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime('09:00:00'),
    new DateInterval('PT30M'),
    new DateTime('18:00:00')
);

foreach ($timeRange as $time) {
    $options[$time->format('H:m')] = $time->format('H:m');
}
```

I am expecting to get a list of times out of this that starts at `09:00, 09:30, 10:00, 10:30`... and every half hour to ...`16:30, 17:00, 17:30, 18:00`.

What I'm actually getting is this list of times:

```
09:10, 10:10, 11:10, 12:10, 13:10, 14:10, 15:10, 16:10, 17:10
```

As you can see, this is wrong on two counts: it is incrementing by an hour each time rather than half an hour, and it is starting at an arbitrary time ten minutes past the hour.

Both of these are consistent; it isn't based on the time I ran the code, for example.

I also tried adding a hard-coded date to the `DateTime` classes, so that they looked like this:

```
new DateTime('2018-01-01 09:00:00')
```

This changed the output such that all the results were one minute past the hour. Again, it incremented by an hour each time.

I can't explain this behaviour. It seems to be completely wrong. Can anyone explain it, and tell me what I need to do to fix this.

I can, of course, revert to using timestamps; I have code for this that works already. But I would like to know what is going on with the `DatePeriod`.

For reference, this is running under PHP 7.2.4.

Comment: `format('H:m')` -- `m` is month, `i` is minute.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: @aynber Dang I thought I had that one, you beat me by 30 secs heh.

Comment: Haha! Thank you. I knew I must be doing something dumb. Problem solved.  :-)

Comment: I was working on an example, got a phone call, then came back to see @AlexHowansky had it answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$options[$time->format('H:m')] = $time->format('H:m');
```

`m` is the month identifier. You want `i`:

```
$options[$time->format('H:i')] = $time->format('H:i');
```